# How to avoid unwanted duration on excel gantt chart?

Tags: excel, gantt-chart

**How to avoid unwanted duration on excel gantt chart?**

I have prepared a gantt chart from simplest table of (start, duration, description). However, in the actual chart I always see starting date is 3 months ahead. I want to start from exact start of my chart data. How to resolve it?

Just followed the tutorial [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/23/make-gantt-chart-excel/)

[image]

Comment: Seems OP wants to avoid Jan-Mar duration as his data starts from Apr.

Comment: This is probably better suited for SuperUser.com